# Routing in Node & Express: app.use does not work unless full path is provided

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have the following setup:

```
app.use('/', rootRoute);
app.use('/wiki', wikiRoute);

/// default handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

If I visit `/wiki`, I end up in `wikiRoute`, as expected, but if I visit `/wiki/some/file`, it triggers the default handler. I would expect it to also go to `wikiRoute` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handling of sub-routes requires wildcards, like so:

```
app.use('/', rootRoute);
app.use('/wiki/*', wikiRoute);

/// default handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

Now, `/wiki/some/file` also ends up in `wikiRoute`!